# With Nodejs, why can I read from one Azure blob container but not from another?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

I have a nodejs app running as a Worker Role in Azure Cloud Services where I have two blob storage containers that the app will read from when responding to certain user requests.

Here's my setup:
Using the [azure-storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) package to interface with my blob storage.
Two containers, each holding files of different types that the user may ask for at some point.

And I use the following code to stream the files to the HTTP response:

```
exports.getBlobToStream = function(containerName, fileName, res) {
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();

    blobService.getBlobProperties(containerName, fileName, function(error, properties, status){
        if(error || !status.isSuccessful)
        {
            res.header('Content-Type', "text/plain");
            res.status(404).send("File " + fileName + " not found");
        }
        else
        {
            res.header('Content-Type', properties.contentType);
            res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            blobService.createReadStream(containerName, fileName).pipe(res);
        }
    });
};
```

One important

In the past I've had no issues reading from either container. In my research on the problemI've found an identical (but outdated) issue on the all-encompassing azure-sdk-for-node here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/434. The solution that fixed that problem also fixed mine, but I can't understand why. Particularly when I can read from the other container from within the same app and using the same code without any issues.

I can live with the solution but want to understand what's going on. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@winsome, thanks for raising this issue to us. If you set EMULATED, it means the code will call the local storage emulator other than the real storage account and expected to fail. Regarding the one container works under EMULATED, a guess is your local storage emulator also has a same container. Please check.